# Добавляя значение в словарь, созданный dict.fromkeys(), оно добавляется для всех ключей. В чем причина и как решить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Добавляя в словарь, созданный при помощи dict.fromkeys() значения, они добавляются сразу для ВСЕХ ключей. Код ниже:

```
 path = './wiki/'
 files = dict.fromkeys(os.listdir(path), [])
 files['Abducens_nerve'].append('Bob')
```

Результат:

```
 {'14th_Chess_Olympiad': ['Bob'],
 '1978_South_Lebanon_conflict': ['Bob'],
 '2017_Serbian_protests': ['Bob'],
 '25th_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution': ['Bob'],
 'Abducens_nerve': ['Bob']}
```

А для словаря, созданного руками такой проблемы нет:

```
 list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 list2 = [123, 234, 456]
 d = {'a': [], 'b': []}
 d['a'].append('a')
 d['a'].append(list1)
```

Результат, значения добавлены только ключу 'a':

```
 {'a': ['a', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], 'b': []}
```

Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 6):

> А для словаря, созданного руками такой проблемы нет:

Это потому что у вас используется один объект списка на всех ключи.

Этот код

```
files = dict.fromkeys(os.listdir(path), [])
```

тоже самое что:

```
value = []
files = {k: value for k in os.listdir(path)}
```

Для наглядности:

```
files = dict.fromkeys('abcd', [])
print(files)
# {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': []}

files['a'].append(1)
print(files)
# {'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}
```

---

Чтобы код работал как задумано, нужно создавать новый список на каждый ключ:

```
files = {k: [] for k in os.listdir(path)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
keys = [ '14th_Chess_Olympiad',
         '1978_South_Lebanon_conflict',
         '2017_Serbian_protests',
         '25th_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution',
         'Abducens_nerve']

value = []

files = {key: list(value) for key in keys}
print( files )
{'14th_Chess_Olympiad': [], 'Abducens_nerve': [], '25th_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution': [], '2017_Serbian_protests': [], '1978_South_Lebanon_conflict': []}

files['Abducens_nerve'].append('Bob')
print( files )
{'14th_Chess_Olympiad': [], 'Abducens_nerve': ['Bob'], '25th_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution': [], '2017_Serbian_protests': [], '1978_South_Lebanon_conflict': []}
```